Problem with trigger in pqsql
BEGIN
    SELECT n_volume_ritardo
    FROM Lettore
    WHERE cf = d.cf;
    IF n_volume_ritardo >= 5 THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END;

The system says
ERROR:  trigger functions cannot have declared arguments
HINT:  The arguments of the trigger can be accessed through TG_NARGS and TG_ARGV instead. 

I can't understand where I went wrong.

Your mistake was not to read the documentation:

A data change trigger is declared as a function with no arguments and a return type of trigger. Note that the function must be declared with no arguments even if it expects to receive some arguments specified in CREATE TRIGGER — such arguments are passed via TG_ARGV, as described below.

